# Getting the Error "Error: The argument type 'BoxConstraints' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'"

Tags: flutter, dart

I am Getting the following error.

```
lib/screens/bottom_navigation/dashboard_screen.dart:91:21: Error: The argument type 'BoxConstraints' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BoxConstraints' is from 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/box.dart').
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
    ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: screenWidth, maxHeight: screenHeight),
```

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    dynamic screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    dynamic screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    ScreenUtil.init(BoxConstraints(maxWidth: screenWidth, maxHeight: screenHeight),
        designSize: Size(360, 690), orientation: Orientation.portrait);
```

I am new to flutter. Please tell me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
ScreenUtil.init(context, designSize: const Size(360, 690),orientation: Orientation.portrait);

    return Scaffold();

}
```